# PHP PDO trying to get navbar to change when logged in

Tags: php, mysql, css, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

I am trying to get my navbar to change when logged in so that the register and sign in turn into the user's username I have my code for this and I am not understanding why it's not working...

signin.php

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'ini.php';

$username = "";
$password = "";

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if ($userQuery->execute()) {
        while ($row = $userQuery->fetch()) {

            $username = $_POST["username"];
            $password = $_POST["password"];

            $userQuery = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :username");
            $addUserQuery->bindParam(":username", $username);

            if (
                username == $row['User_Username'] && password == $row['User_Password']
            ) {
                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "true";
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-3'></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="login-box well">
                <form action="index.php" id="login" name="login">
                    <legend>Sign In</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input value='' id="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input id="password" value='' placeholder="Password" type="text" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" class="btn btn-default btn-login-submit btn-block m-t-md" value="Login" />
                    </div>
                    <span class='text-center'><a href="/resetting/request" class="text-sm">Forgot Password?</a></span>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p class="text-center m-t-xs text-sm">Do not have an account?</p>
                        <a href="register.php" class="btn btn-default btn-block m-t-md">Create an account</a>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3'></div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Web Development company providing HTML, CSS, PHP and JS in your local area">
    <meta name="author" content="Kieran Brownfield">

    <title>Web Development Penzance - Providing Web Development in your area</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
<header class="header">Web Development Penzance</header>
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Meet the Team</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {  ?>
                    <li><p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as: <?php echo $_SESSION["username"] ?> &nbsp;</p></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="signin.php">Login</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the $_SESSION variable across page loads, add `session_start()` to the top of both of these files.  [Docs.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: `session_start()` is PHP, so yes, it should be in your PHP

Comment: OK, the more I look at this, the more errors I see.  The action on your sign-in form is index.php - where is that file?  Is it doing what you think it does? Should that file actually hold your code block that checks the database and sets the session? You can't execute() $userQuery before you prepare() it, and you're missing a `$` in another if statement.  All that said, there's probably too much going on here at the moment to fix on SO.........

Comment: index.php just calls the header and the footer as I haven't put any data into these yet